# CSS border overflowing outside div

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

If I add 1's to the days until head the border will overflow outside the div, so if it's 113 days left it will overflow, or if it's maybe a different month the border will "overflow" outside the div. What I want is for the border to stay "static" the whole time.

[image]
The html

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="show-info">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Show Name</th>
            <th>Season | Episode</th>
            <th>Days Until Release</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {{#each show}}
          <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>1 Mar. 2018 </td>
            <td>14 days left f(1 Mar. 2018)</td>
            <!-- <td>{{this.showData.show_name}}</td>
            <!-- <td>{{this.showData.seasons.[5].[13].airdate}}</td> -->
            <!-- <td>{{daysUntilShow this.showData.seasons.[5].[13].airdate}} days left f({{this.showData.seasons.[5].[13].airdate}})</td> --> -->
          </tr>
          {{/each}}
        </tbody>

      </table>
```

The CSS (also if there is something better I could do please let me know)

```
#title {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #05c46b;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 20px;
}

#title:hover {
  color: rgb(5,196,107);
}

.button {
  float: right;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(#1e272e, #485460);
}


.show-info th, td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  overflow: visible;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 107px;
  max-width: 158px;
  min-width: 104px;
  padding-right: 26%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */

}

.show-info th:last-child, td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.airing {
  background-color:#44bd32;
}
```

Comment: why are you using that weird padding-right:26% instead of simply text-align-center???

Comment: I forgot I could do that, I took  a course on HTML and CSS so I haven't explored much. this is my first website, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I created [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5ororgan/16/)  fiddle and couldn't reproduce this specific issue.
Please specify your problem a bit more and make sure that none of your global css definitions (if there are some) collide with this code chunk.

Comment: are you expecting like this? https://jsfiddle.net/954vqas3/4/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Yes, exactly that

Comment: @SkylarLopez added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the padding form your styles `padding: 0px 107px;` and `padding-right: 26%;`. Instead of this you can use `text-align:center` and make it center of the td. Also apply `width:100%` for your table and divide equally for each `td`. This is optional. If you want some `td` need to big and some `td` need to small, you can decide and apply based on that for your td's in a percentage. So that any screen it will calculate accordingly. I have modified and added the following styles.

```
 .show-info table {
    width:100%;
 }
 .show-info th, td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    overflow: visible;
    color: white;
    width:33%;
   /*padding: 0px 107px;
   max-width: 158px;*/
   min-width: 104px;
   /*padding-right: 26%;*/
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   text-align:center;
   border-right: 1px solid white;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
}
```

The same above I have added in the following snippet.

```css
#title {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #05c46b;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 20px;
}

#title:hover {
  color: rgb(5,196,107);
}

.button {
  float: right;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(#1e272e, #485460);
}

.show-info table {
  width:100%;
}
.show-info th, td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  overflow: visible;
  color: white;
  width:33%;
  /*padding: 0px 107px;*/
  /*max-width: 158px;*/
  min-width: 104px;
  /*padding-right: 26%;*/
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align:center;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */

}

.show-info th:last-child, td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.airing {
  background-color:#44bd32;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="show-info">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Show Name</th>
            <th>Season | Episode</th>
            <th>Days Until Release</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          
          <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>1 Mar. 2018 </td>
            <td>14 days left f(1 Mar. 2018)</td>            
          </tr>
          
        </tbody>

      </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation!